# Combining two indicator to one

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I'm trying to combine 2 indicator to one.

The first one is a really simple one I made my self. It's 2 different ema built into one indicator.
The second I would like to integrate is the "multi time frame EMA".

At the end, I want my indicator to display 2 ema normally and I want a 3rd one that will be a 50 period ema displaying the h1 time frame. For exemple: on the 15 minutes charts, I will have ema1 = ema 20, ema2 = ema 50, ema 3 = ema 50 from the 1h time frame.

I am in my first baby step as a "pine script coder" and I didn't find how to do it by my self.

My multiple indicator script:

```
indicator('EMA', overlay=true)
ema1 = ta.ema(close, length=input(title='ema1', defval=50))
plot(ema1, title='ema1', color=#f80000)
ema2 = ta.ema(close, length=input(title='ema2', defval=200))
plot(ema2, title='ema3', color=#000000)
```

The one I would like to add:

```
study("Multi Time Frame Exponential Moving Average", "MTF EMA", overlay=true)
ma_len = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=100)
src = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
ma_offset = input(title="Offset", type=integer, defval=0)
res = input(title="Resolution", type=resolution, defval="240")
htf_ma = ema(src, ma_len)
out = security(tickerid, res, htf_ma)
plot(out, color=red, offset=ma_offset)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to merge two script, make sure that they have the same `pinescript` version.

Your first script is written in `v5` and your second script seems to be written in `v1` or `v2` or `v3`.

If you don't have a version identifier, just add `//@version=3` to top of your script and either convert it to `v5` manually or use the auto converter tool.

Use the [Migration Guideline](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html) when you need support.